# ZNC - Cheat IRC server's connections from ip limit

Tags: dns, ip, debian, irc

I want to connect more than 5 bouncers to my favourite irc network.
Unfortunately, server accepts only up to five connections from one IP.
How can i do it and is it real?
I have only one server with one IP but i have a domain with an unlimited number pf subdomains.

Comment: On a side note, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a proxy server.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Comment: Yeah, i know, but how can i do it with ZNC?

Answer (score 0):

Either ask the network for a connection limit exemption (which a network should be able to give you if you explain why you need it), or you'll need a second IP or a second server - there's no way around this.

With a second machine, you could set up a bouncer on that machine (such as irssi with irssi-proxy), then  connect ZNC to irssi. Alternatively, you could use SSH tunnelling to route your IRC connection through another machine.

Neither method is particularly good, multiple ZNC instances on multiple machines, or an exemption is probably the best way. Talk to the network staff about it and see what they can do.